# Recursive function to return the average of the digits in a number

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that returns the average of the digits in a number. For example the average of the number 123 is 2.
I know how to write a function that sums the digits.

```
public static int sum (int n) {
    if (n<10)
        return n;
    return n%10 + sum(n/10);
}
```

I also know how to count the digits

```
public static int numCount(int n) {
    if (n<10)
        return 1;
    return 1 + numCount(n/10);
}
```

However I can't figure out how to calculate the average without using pre existing functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average

Comment: why not use `double sum(123)/numCount(123)`?

Comment: If it's whole numbers only then. All you need to do is

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively iterate the array while keeping both accumulative `sum` and an index that shows which items were already iterated:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        System.out.println(avg(arr)); // 2.0
    }

    private static double avg(int[] arr) {
        return avg(arr, 0, 0);
    }

    private static double avg(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
        if (index == arr.length) {
            return (double) sum / index;
        }
        return avg(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/IHm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int recursive(int num, int startingSize) {
    if(num < 10){
        return num;
    }
    num = num % 10 + recursive(num/10, startingSize++);

    return num/startingSize;

}
```

and for example : `recursive(123, 1)`

Comment: Can you do it without the parameter startingSize

Comment: `int count(int num) {
  return recursive(num, 1);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0;
public static int sum (int n) {
    count++;
    if (n<10)
        return n;
    return n%10 + sum(n/10);
}

double average = (double)sum(123)/count;
System.out.println("average:"+ average);
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean if we are just talking numbers we don't even need recursive functions here

```
String s = Double(10.45).toString();
Int size = s.length();
int count = 0;
Int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; I++ ) {
     try {
           sum += Integer.valueOf(s[i]);
           ++count;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

return sum / count;
```

That should give you an. Average regardless of number, whole or real.